# how to display date format in x axis using wxmplot

Tags: python, wxmpl

I am plotting a real time trend graph using wxmplot. However, I could not find a way to display the X axis data in date time format

I have tried a various types of data for x, such as string in date format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`, timestamp and finally `time.time()` and I have set the `use_date=True in plot(self.x, self.y, use_dates=True)`.

```
self.x = np.array([time()])
self.y = np.array([random.randint(0, 10)])

 self.panel_1 = PlotPanel(self, size=(400, 400))
 self.panel_1.plot(self.x, self.y, use_dates=True)
```

With time() as the data for the x, the graph display float values, instead of date format, such as '2019-10-17 12:12:00'.
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some of my codes and plotpanel.py. According the author of the wxmplot, there was a typo error in plotpanel.py, I have changed the use_datas to use_dates according, and modified to the following.

```
self.x = np.array([time()-20, time()])
self.y = np.array([random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)])
```

It works after all these changes in plot function and displaying date format accordingly.

When you need to update the graph in real time, you need to convert x axis data using dates.datet2num first before calling update_line.

```
self.x = np.append(self.x, [time()])
xdata=[dates.date2num(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i)) for i in self.x]
self.y = np.append(self.y, [random.randint(0, 10)])
self.panel_1.update_line(0, xdata, self.y, draw=True)
```